# lodash: check object is empty

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this object:
`{"": undefined}`

and when I check this object for empty in this way:
`_.isEmpty({"": undefined})`

I get `false` result, maybe in lodash we have another method?

Comment: Why do you think the object is empty? It has one valid key.

Comment: FYI, `{}` is an empty object.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your example object *is **not** empty* so instead perhaps you want to test if all properties are *undefined*

```
let o = {foo: undefined};
!_.values(o).some(x => x !== undefined); // true
```

Answer (score 60):

```
_.isEmpty(obj, true)
```

```js
var obj = {
  'firstName': undefined
, 'lastName' : undefined
};

console.log(_.isEmpty(obj)); // false
console.log(_.isEmpty({})); // true
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Please, see http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2012/08/18/determining-if-an-object-is-empty-with-underscore-lo-dash/

Comment: Hi @Deano. What is the problem.

Comment: -1 for lack of clarity. Future readers: Note that isEmpty does **not** take any second argument. Consulting lodash's docs for this would only leave your more stumped. This functionality only comes when you write your own **mixin** and apply that to isEmpty. This answer should really specify how that happens. Read the linked blog post for more details.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on how you want to check it. 
Do you want to check [some](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some) or [every](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#every)

Then what you can do is :

```
import { some, isEmpty } from 'lodash'
console.log(some(this.yourObject, isEmpty))
```

Answer (score 5):

In your case it cannot be called an empty object (`Object.values(obj).length` would return 1), but for a completely empty object this can be used:

```js
import { matches } from 'lodash';
matches(obj, {});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it this way

```
_.isEmpty(_.omitBy(object_to_check, _.isNil)
```

_.omitBy removes all the keys with null & undefined values in this example.
To remove only undefined you can use `_.isUndefined` instead of `_.isNil`

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is a bit overkill, but this is what I use which recursively checks for nested objects too and uses `lodash`.

```
function checkEmptyObject(obj) {
  if (_.isEmpty(obj)) return true;
  return _.isEmpty(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, value]) => {
        if (_.isEmpty(value)) return true;
        if (value instanceof Object) return checkEmptyObject(value);
        return false;
      })
      .filter((b) => b === false)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To provide an alternative to Lodash - this is how I do the same with vanilla JS ES6.

```js
const isEmpty = (obj) => {
    return obj === undefined ? true : Object.keys(obj).length === 0
}

console.log(isEmpty(undefined))
console.log(isEmpty({}))
```

Comment: Sadly, this method will throw an error if the `obj` is `null` exactly. ("TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object")

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
_.omitBy(
            obj,
            (v) =>
                _.isUndefined(v) ||
                _.isNull(v) ||
                v === '' ||
                (v && v instanceof Object && Object.keys(v).length === 0)
        );
```