# ES6 Object.assign(): why do undefined properties override defined properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why does the following snippet return `{ a: 3, b: undefined }` and not `{ a: 3, b: 2 }`?

```js
console.log(Object.assign({ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: undefined }));
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977214) asks about a function that gives the latter output instead of the former, but my question is why was `Object.assign()` designed this way?  Or to put it a different way, what exactly are the differences between `{ a: 3 }` and `{ a: 3, b: undefined }`?

**UPDATE** (from the comments on apsillers answer):

`{ a: 1 }` says "I have no property named 'b'", `{ a: 1, b: undefined }` says "I have a property 'b' but it has not yet been given a value", and `{ a: 1, b: null }` says "I have a property 'b' that should hold an object but has not yet been given an object to hold". Since in the latter two the object has a property 'b', regardless of what the value is, it will still override non-null non-undefined values when passed into `Object.assign()`.

Comment: `{a: 3}` does not have a property called "b" at all, while `{a: 3, b: undefined}` does.

Comment: in the second case, you have a value.

Comment: It's the _presence_ of a property that determines whether it's copied, not the value.

Comment: Slightly related: [Why an object where all its properties are undefined is not listed as empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520607/691711).  `undefined` is a value and shouldn't just be ignored.  As to ***why*** it was designed this way, I think that may be too broad because it asked for intentions behind a design.

Comment: An excellent question with a code snippet demonstrating the outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{ a: 3 }` has one property, whose key is the string "`a`". You can observe this by `Object.keys({a:3})`, which returns `["a"]`.

`{ a: 3, b: undefined }` has two properties, one called `a` and another called `b`. Calling `Object.keys({a: 3, b: undefined})` returns `["a", "b"]`.

`Object.assign` uses values from whatever (enumerable) properties exist on each incoming object, and `assign`'s specification does not handle specially the case where a property happens to have the value `undefined`.

Comment: It sort of makes sense that `Object.keys({ a: 1 })` returns `["a"]` whereas `Object.keys({ a: 1, b: undefined })` returns `["a", "b"]`, but it also sort of doesn't.  I thought JavaScript maintained `undefined` separately from `null` specifically because `null` communicates "this property exists and has no value" whereas `undefined` communicates "this property does not exist".  Hence why `{ a: 1 }.completelyMadeUpPropertyName` returns `undefined`.

Comment: @Dominus `undefined` signifies the lack of a value (but not necessarily the absence of a property, just as we may have defined variables with the value `undefined` so too may we have properties that hold `undefined`) whereas `null` signifies "the intentional absence of any object value" according to the ES5 spec; i.e., `null` specifically indicates an object context/value, but the santics of having no actual value. `null` is, overall, a really dumb feature of the language.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  So `{ a: 1 }` says "I have no property named 'b'", `{ a: 1, b: undefined }` says "I have a property 'b' but it has not yet been given a value", and `{ a: 1, b: null }` says "I have a property 'b' that has intentionally been given no value".  Does that sound right?

Comment: @Dominus.Vobiscum Strictly according to the spec, `null` means something like "this should hold an object, and the current value is no-object" but otherwise, that's a pretty good summary.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thanks for answering a somewhat esoteric question!