# better way to validate the fields in the javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to validate the object so that the object is not null and few of the fields in that object is not empty.

For example, consider the following object:

```
address ={
    block : '2134',
    street : 'berly street',
    county : 'someCountry'
    postal : '876546'
}
```

I am using es6. I found the solution to do this [using lodash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523996/lodash-check-object-is-empty)

I want to do this in plain JS.
Please let me know if there is a better way to do this than below:

```
 const isValidAddress = (address) => {

      const addressFields = ['block', 'county', 'postal', 'street'];
      return addressFields.every((element) => address[element] && address[element].length > 0);
};
```

Comment: You can use `Object.keys`

Comment: @CertainPerformance My bad, that was a typo. I have changed to `every()`

Comment: That's not an answer but a suggestion : You could switch to typescript and use typeguards

Comment: Why the down vote? please mention the reason

Comment: @CharybdeBE unfortunately that is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try checking every value with [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this.

```js
const invalidAdress ={
    block: '',
    street: 'berly street',
    county: 'someCountry',
    postal: '876546'
};

const validAdress ={
    block: '1234',
    street: 'berly street',
    county: 'someCountry',
    postal: '876546'
};

// .every will return true if and only if every property in the object is a truthy value
const isValidAddress = (address) => Object.keys(address).every(x => address[x]);

console.log(isValidAddress(invalidAdress));
console.log(isValidAddress(validAdress));
```

Comment: Object.keys is a good option, at least that what it looks like in the beginning but it will not solve the purpose if some property is entirely missing, but that's a different problem altogether

Comment: @codeMan that wont solve it, but checking for missing properties is another task by itself.