# React validate object using map to avoid null values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, mapping

What would be the alternative to `&& !(Object.keys(dataSource.attributes).length === 0));` the following validation, any ways of this to be a map of validation / title / render

```js
isProductAttributesTabEmpty() {
  const dataSource = this.getDataSource();

  return !(dataSource
    && dataSource.attributes
    && !(Object.keys(dataSource.attributes).length === 0));
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't really help. I still don't know what you're trying to accomplish. Also, there is no `map` method in your current code.

Comment: @nick `!(Object.keys(dataSource.attributes).length === 0));` is there a better way of doing the following validation? =) Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: can't use map but can loop over Object as``` for(key in Object)```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62294742/5737562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you might prefer would be to use optional chaining in combination with alternating with an empty object to pass into `Object.keys`:

```
isProductAttributesTabEmpty() {
  const dataSource = this.getDataSource();
  return Object.keys(dataSource?.attributes || {}).length === 0;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use `.map()`, or `.filter()` over? or the for-in loop?

Comment: Nice use of the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) ;)

Comment: @SharedUser `.map` and `.filter` don't help because you don't need to iterate over arrays, except to check their `.length`. `for..in` could be used but would be really verbose, better to use `.length`